# Xcode build results frame

Tags: xcode

When I launch the build on XCode, the build results annoying frame [(check the image)](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/2802/editinginxcode.png) just pop out and this is really not very ergonomic. Since I don't have any solution, can you give me some tips to make Xcode more ergonomic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Preferences` => `Building` => `Build Results Window:` => `Open during builds:` => `Never`

[image]